# Parameter @un must be defined

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm getting this error

> "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Fatal error encountered
> during command execution.", "MySqlException: Parameter '@un' must be
> defined."

and I don't know what to do honestly I'm just following what my friend is doing and I'm just a complete newbie in coding. Here is my code.

```
private void BTNDELETE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var c = cmd.Parameters;
              
        con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.sampledb_it11ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd = new MySqlCommand("delete tbl_user set username=@un, password=@pw, usertype=@ut, loginname=@ln where username=@un,", con); 
        c.Clear();
        c.AddWithValue("@un", TXTUN.Text);
        c.AddWithValue("@pw", TXTPW.Text);
        c.AddWithValue("@ut", CBOUT.Text);
        c.AddWithValue("@ln", TXTLN.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Record has been deleted", "Deleting Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        TXTUN.Text = "";
        TXTPW.Text = "";
        TXTCPW.Text = "";
        TXTLN.Text = "";
        CBOUT.Text = "";
        TXTUN.Focus();
        DG_Refresh();

        TXTUN.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: `delete tbl_user set...` is not proper sql. Are you really trying to delete, or are you trying to UPDATE?

Comment: What are you try to do exactly? I'm not familiar with MySQL but looks like there is no `SET` for `DELETE` statement. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html Are you try to `UPDATE` instead? Your sql query looks wrong.

Comment: As for your error, MySql uses positional parameters, not named, so you need to add another parameter for the second use of `un`. However, you have to decide if you are deleting or updating first.

Comment: Oh sorry I am trying to delete a record, what should be the proper statement?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Comment: @steven This is depends on your `tbl_user` structure and what you try to but maybe you just want delete your user like this? `delete from tbl_user where username=@un`? Again, this is just an assumption.

Comment: @SonerGönül I'm trying to delete the whole record including the username, password, user type and the login name.

Comment: @steven Then add them to your `where` clause as well.

Comment: DELETEing deletes a whole row, you do not have to pass all the fields that you want to delete, you just need a WHERE clause that limits the rows to just the one(s) you want.

Comment: @SonerGönül I don't think you read OP's last comment carefully and yours is probably causing confusion.

Comment: @Crowcoder What parameter should I add for the second use of @un?

Comment: @steven Since I am not familiar with your data, I cannot tell you. Typically if you want to delete a single row, you put as many columns in the WHERE clause as are required to uniquely identify the row. In your case `un` probably uniquely identifies the row, but there is no way for me to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The error or "MySqlException: Parameter '@un' must be defined." is caused by undefined parameters of the MySqlCommand object. It is incorrect to store the parameters in 'c':

> var c = cmd.Parameters;

> c.AddWithValue("@un", TXTUN.Text);

I would suggest you revise it to :

> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", TXTUN.Text);

Additionally, the sql scripts are messed up. From the MessageBox and the name of button, it seems you mean to delete a row in the database. So the script should be:

> cmd = new MySqlCommand("delete tbl_user where username=@un,", con);

Looks like what your friend do is to update a row while you are going to delete a row. The keyword 'set' should be paired with 'update' command.

And it is incorrect to create a new instance of MySqlCommand after assigning the connection.

```
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd = new MySqlCommand...
```

Finally, the code statements would be like this:

```
con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.sampledb_it11ConnectionString;
con.Open();

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("delete tbl_user where username=@un,", con);
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", TXTUN.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to see connection string and add allow-user-variables to true :
https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/allow-user-variables/#google_vignette